# TypeError: el.getNode is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I upgraded react-native version from v0.61.0 to 0.65.0 using [rn community upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.0&to=0.65.0)
.

After making changes in the package.json file, running npm install, cleaning the build folder in android, the build gets successful and the app launches with an error screen.

```
TypeError: el.getNode is not a function

This error is located at:
    in AndroidHorizontalScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1784)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1810)
    in ScrollView (at AnimatedScrollView.js:22)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:243)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:296)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at TabBar.js:382)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at TabBar.js:381)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:243)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:296)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at TabBar.js:366)
    in TabBar (at MaterialTopTabBar.js:145)
    in TabBarTop (at createMaterialTopTabNavigator.js:101)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at TabView.js:190)
    in TabView (at createMaterialTopTabNavigator.js:247)
    in MaterialTabView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at RootTabs.js:218)
    in RootTabs (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at DrawerView.js:188)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:36)
```

I have also updated react-navigation from 3.x to 4.x.Still no success.
I am not able to understand what this snippet is referring to.

```
TypeError: el.getNode is not a function
```

I am struggling to run android as of now. Not tested on ios build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I was using the react-navigation-tabs package in my application.Go to node_modules > react-navigation-tabs > node_modules > react-navigation-tab-view > src > TabBar.js.

In this TabBar.js file, you will find `ref={el => (this._scrollView = el && el.getNode())}` on line 412.

If you check this._scrollView is assigned to `_scrollView: ?ScrollView;` on line 147 which is imported from ScrollView of react-native.

Since ScrollView does not contain any el or el.getNode() method,the bundler throws the error showing el.getNode() is undefined.

To fix this follow these steps:

- Use `Import {Animated} from react-native;`
- On line 147, change fault code to `_scrollView: Animated.ScrollView;`
- On line 412, change faulty code to `(this.scrollView = el && (el.getNode ? el.getNode() : el))`
- Clean and rebuild your project,it should work fine now.

I was able to resolve this error by following this [link](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/845)

Whosoever is getting this problem can refer to this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid calling getNode() in general. It also works.
For instance I had:

`_scrollView.current.getNode().scrollTo({x: x, y: 0, animated: true})`

and just changed it to:

`_scrollView.current.scrollTo({x: x, y: 0, animated: true})`.

Solved the issue and the error was gone. Apparently the creators are luctant about correcting this.

**Check this out**
https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/1138